# Plotting using pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have this set of data:

```
\pgfplotstableread{
x y
64  3.4
65  3.8
66  3.4
66  3.5
68  3.3
69  3.1
69  4.1
70  3.9
70  4
70  4.1
70  4.1
71  3.6
71  3.7
71  3.9
71  4
72  4.3
73  3.6
73  4.1
73  4.3
73  4.5
73  4.5
73  4.5
73  4.7
74  3.3
74  3.8
74  4.2
74  4.4
74  4.5
74  4.5
75  3.8
75  3.8
75  4.1
75  4.2
75  4.5
75  4.7
75  4.8
75  4.8
76  3.9
76  4
76  4.1
76  4.2
76  4.2
76  4.3
76  4.6
76  4.8
76  5.1
77  4
77  4
77  4.3
77  4.3
77  4.4
77  4.4
77  4.5
77  4.6
77  4.6
77  4.6
77  4.8
77  5
78  3.5
78  3.8
78  3.9
78  4
78  4.1
78  4.2
78  4.2
78  4.3
78  4.4
78  4.6
78  4.6
78  4.7
78  4.7
78  4.8
78  4.8
79  3.6
79  3.7
79  4
79  4.1
79  4.3
79  4.3
79  4.4
79  4.4
79  4.5
79  4.6
80  3.8
80  4
80  4.4
80  4.5
80  4.6
80  4.7
80  4.8
80  4.8
81  3.7
81  3.8
81  4.1
81  4.1
81  4.2
81  4.2
81  4.2
81  4.3
81  4.3
81  4.5
81  4.6
81  4.6
81  4.8
82  3.8
82  4
82  4.3
82  4.3
82  4.4
82  4.4
82  4.4
82  4.5
82  4.5
82  4.6
82  4.8
82  4.9
83  3.3
83  3.6
83  3.6
83  3.8
83  4.2
83  4.3
83  4.3
83  4.4
83  4.5
83  4.5
83  4.5
83  4.5
83  4.7
83  4.9
84  3.9
84  3.9
84  4.1
84  4.1
84  4.5
84  4.5
84  4.6
84  4.7
84  4.7
84  4.8
85  3.6
85  4
85  4.4
85  4.5
85  4.6
85  4.6
86  4
86  4.2
86  4.2
86  4.9
86  4.9
86  4.9
87  3.5
87  4.4
88  4.2
88  4.4
88  4.6
88  4.7
88  4.9
88  5
89  4
89  4.3
89  4.9
90  4.3
90  4.4
90  4.5
90  4.7
90  4.7
90  4.8
91  4.1
92  4.4
93  4.1
93  4.6
94  4.8
96  5.1
}\MyData
```

I want to add this set of data as coordinates in a graph. The coordinates should be like this

```
\addplot [black, thin, only marks,mark=*, fill=blue!60!white, mark size=2.6pt]
```

I've tried to figure this out for a while now, might be something small that i'm missing. Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Append `table{\MyData};` to your addplot (page 47 of pgfplots manual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I went ahead and tested it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
x y
64  3.4
65  3.8
66  3.4
66  3.5
68  3.3
69  3.1
69  4.1
70  3.9
70  4
70  4.1
70  4.1
71  3.6
71  3.7
71  3.9
71  4
72  4.3
73  3.6
73  4.1
73  4.3
73  4.5
73  4.5
73  4.5
73  4.7
74  3.3
74  3.8
74  4.2
74  4.4
74  4.5
74  4.5
75  3.8
75  3.8
75  4.1
75  4.2
75  4.5
75  4.7
75  4.8
75  4.8
76  3.9
76  4
76  4.1
76  4.2
76  4.2
76  4.3
76  4.6
76  4.8
76  5.1
77  4
77  4
77  4.3
77  4.3
77  4.4
77  4.4
77  4.5
77  4.6
77  4.6
77  4.6
77  4.8
77  5
78  3.5
78  3.8
78  3.9
78  4
78  4.1
78  4.2
78  4.2
78  4.3
78  4.4
78  4.6
78  4.6
78  4.7
78  4.7
78  4.8
78  4.8
79  3.6
79  3.7
79  4
79  4.1
79  4.3
79  4.3
79  4.4
79  4.4
79  4.5
79  4.6
80  3.8
80  4
80  4.4
80  4.5
80  4.6
80  4.7
80  4.8
80  4.8
81  3.7
81  3.8
81  4.1
81  4.1
81  4.2
81  4.2
81  4.2
81  4.3
81  4.3
81  4.5
81  4.6
81  4.6
81  4.8
82  3.8
82  4
82  4.3
82  4.3
82  4.4
82  4.4
82  4.4
82  4.5
82  4.5
82  4.6
82  4.8
82  4.9
83  3.3
83  3.6
83  3.6
83  3.8
83  4.2
83  4.3
83  4.3
83  4.4
83  4.5
83  4.5
83  4.5
83  4.5
83  4.7
83  4.9
84  3.9
84  3.9
84  4.1
84  4.1
84  4.5
84  4.5
84  4.6
84  4.7
84  4.7
84  4.8
85  3.6
85  4
85  4.4
85  4.5
85  4.6
85  4.6
86  4
86  4.2
86  4.2
86  4.9
86  4.9
86  4.9
87  3.5
87  4.4
88  4.2
88  4.4
88  4.6
88  4.7
88  4.9
88  5
89  4
89  4.3
89  4.9
90  4.3
90  4.4
90  4.5
90  4.7
90  4.7
90  4.8
91  4.1
92  4.4
93  4.1
93  4.6
94  4.8
96  5.1
}\MyData

%\pgfplotstabletypeset{\MyData}% verify data

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [black, thin, only marks,mark=*, fill=blue!60!white, mark size=2.6pt] table{\MyData};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]